# Add a subview in xib to a custom UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

First, I have a exist `Asset.m/Asset.h`, it is the `subclass of UIView`. Then I create a empty xib file and change xib's file's owner class to Asset. Then I create a view and a label to this xib, and I can drag and create `IBOutlet` in `UIView`.

```
IBOutlet UIView *videoOverlay;
IBOutlet UILabel *videoTimeLable;
```

Then I want to add **videoOverlay** to Asset.m's view using **addSubview**.

```
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self addSubview:videoOverlay];
```

But the view -- videoOverlay do not show up.

I print out size of videoOverlay, all 0:

```
    NSLog(@"width =%f height= %f", videoOverlay.frame.size.width, videoOverlay.frame.size.height);
```

Why ?

Comment: try [self.view addSubview: videoOverlay]

Comment: It seems **you** have set the size zero, haven't you? `CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);` :D

Comment: YES, But videoOverlay has size in xib file.

Comment: Asset is a UIView, so there hasn't self.view, itself is a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution by myself. Use under code to add this view (videoOverlay and videoTimeLable belong to this view )in:

```
UIView *thumbs;
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ELCAsset" owner:self options:nil];
    thumbs = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addSubview:thumbs];
```

then videoOverlay and videoTimeLable can show up.